# twitter's typeahead not working after build

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, yeoman, typeahead.js

i am building an application using backbone,requirejs with yeoman.

am using twitter's typeaheadjs and it work in development version but its not working after the build! its not even throwing any error

```
this.collection.fetch({
    success: function (data) {
        $('#SerachProduct').typeahead({
            name: 'abc',
            valueKey: 'name',
            local: data.toJSON(),
            template: JST['app/scripts/templates/typeahead.ejs']
        });
    },
    error: fun() {..
    }
}
```

Here is the github repo [Github](https://github.com/Anenth/Invoice-360)

Updates here is the link for the site [application](http://anenth.github.io/Invoice-360/)

```
$('#SerachProduct').typeahead({
  name: 'accounts',
  local: ['timtrueman', 'JakeHarding', 'vskarich']
});
```

Try running this on console ! it still not working ! but its working in development version

**NOTE**:
i tried adding jquery and typeahead lib directly to index files before the requirejs, typeahead didn't work not even in production version even after running the above statement in console, but when i placed it after the requirejs it worked but only through console

Comment: Are you sure it is just typeahead thats not working? I have had issues with Handlebars and JST Templates after the build process in the past.

Comment: ya rest everything is working

Comment: Sounds like something is going wrong during the minification process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was with **bootstrap** ! When i initialized the project yeoman fetched me the bootstrap 2.3 and it was overriding the typeahead ! i replaced the bootstrap with the latest version ! now it works perfectly !